# jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail Error while running GWT application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, gwt-rpc

> Getting error while running a simple GWT application. when I ran by
>   ant through command line it worked fine but after importing in
>   IntelliJ I am getting this error. Don't know why I am getting this
>   error:
>
> ```
> The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
> Code server started in 9.247 s ms
> 2019-11-09 01:07:02.250:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1d54b16e{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:9876}
> 2019-11-09 01:07:02.250:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @10313ms
> **[ERROR] jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC**
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.jreLeakPrevention(JettyLauncher.java:899)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:722)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
> 2019-11-09 01:07:02.307:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
> Starting Jetty on port 8888
>    [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@e59f292{/,file:/Users/pchenchala/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/gwt/mywebapp.4e8f7f71/MyWebApp.c24f5151/run/www/,STARTING}{/Users/pchenchala/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/gwt/mywebapp.4e8f7f71/MyWebApp.c24f5151/run/www}
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file GreetingServiceImpl.class
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:708)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:824)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:702)
>   ... 10 more
> 2019-11-09 01:07:05.521:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@539f3a98{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:8888}
> 2019-11-09 01:07:05.528:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @13591ms
> Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL: 
> http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyWebApp.html
> [ERROR] 503 - GET /MyWebApp.html (127.0.0.1) 301 bytes
>    Request headers
>       Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
>       Connection: keep-alive
>       Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87
> ```
>
> Safari/537.36
>             Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
>             Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
>             Sec-Fetch-Site: none
>             Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
>             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>             Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
>             If-Modified-Since: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 16:26:04 GMT
>          Response headers
>             Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 19:37:05 GMT
>             Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
>             Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>             Content-Length: 301
>       [ERROR] 503 - GET /MyWebApp.html (127.0.0.1) 301 bytes
>          Request headers
>             Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
>             Connection: keep-alive
>             Cache-Control: max-age=0
>             Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>             User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87
>   Safari/537.36
>             Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
>             Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
>             Sec-Fetch-Site: none
>             Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
>             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>             Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
>          Response headers
>             Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 19:39:53 GMT
>             Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
>             Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>             Content-Length: 301
>       GET /clean/mywebapp
>          Cleaning disk caches.
>             Cleaned in 13ms.
>       [ERROR] 503 - GET /MyWebApp.html (127.0.0.1) 301 bytes
>          Request headers
>             Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
>             Connection: keep-alive
>             Cache-Control: max-age=0
>             Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>             User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87
>   Safari/537.36
>             Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
>             Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
>             Sec-Fetch-Site: none
>             Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
>             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>             Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
>          Response headers
>             Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 19:52:14 GMT
>             Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
>             Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>             Content-Length: 301
>
> ```
> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors here, and they are unrelated.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC**
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.jreLeakPrevention(JettyLauncher.java:899)
```

This is safe to ignore. The checks around this are there to protect against this very thing from happening - the JRE implementation you are using removing this feature. Examining JettyLauncher.java in this version of GWT, you find the following code:
https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/a90832fec9a56f4cb83ed009c7048e0a8d196fe8/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/JettyLauncher.java#L898-L915

```
    try {
      Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("sun.misc.GC");
      Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("requestLatency",
          new Class[]{long.class});
      method.invoke(null, Long.valueOf(3600000));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail", e);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
      logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail", e);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail", e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail", e);
    }
```

These catch statements let us log the error, and then resume.

---

Second exception:

```
  [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@e59f292{/,file:/Users/pchenchala/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/gwt/mywebapp.4e8f7f71/MyWebApp.c24f5151/run/www/,STARTING}{/Users/pchenchala/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/gwt/mywebapp.4e8f7f71/MyWebApp.c24f5151/run/www}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file GreetingServiceImpl.class
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:708)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:824)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:702)
  ... 10 more
```

This is a separate error, unrelated to the above, or the title of your post. I'm less sure about what is happening here - best guess, you have some bytecode which asm is unable to read when scanning. Perhaps clean your project and try again?

You might have better luck only posting about this error, since the other error is just a red herring.