# GWT Jetty 9 to 11 ? running Java 21 : sun.misc.GC moved : [ERROR] jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, java-21

is there any way to run it on jetty 11 ?

[image]

Reference [jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail Error while running GWT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773486/jreleakprevention-gcdaemonfail-error-while-running-gwt-application)

(all is running fine on 9.4 only that well known GC message)
I want to force him to jetty 11
by adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

and i get from LOG

```
    /Users/work2/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk- 
 21.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java - agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52523,suspend=y,server=n -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true -Xmx8048m -javaagent:/Users/work2/lombok.jar=ECJ --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/Users/work2/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/gwtproject/gwt-codeserver/2.10.0/gwt-codeserver-2.10.0.jar:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-shop-manager/src/main/java:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-shop-manager/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-shop-manager/target/generated-sources/gwt:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-addins/2.8.2/gwt-material-addins-2.8.2-sources.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-table/2.8.2/gwt-material-table-2.8.2-sources.jar:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity/src/main/java:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity-dao/src/main/java:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity-dao/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity-dao/target/generated-sources/gwt:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-util/src/main/java:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-util/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-util/target/generated-sources/gwt:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-common/src/main/java:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-common/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-common/target/generated-sources/gwt:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-fiscal/src/main/java:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-fiscal/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-fiscal/target/generated-sources/gwt:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-shop-manager/target/ShopManager/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/11.0.16/jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api/5.0.2/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api-5.0.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-http-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/gwtproject/gwt-user/2.10.0/gwt-user-2.10.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/jsinterop/jsinterop-annotations/2.0.0/jsinterop-annotations-2.0.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/gwtproject/gwt-dev/2.10.0/gwt-dev-2.10.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.2/asm-9.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.2/asm-util-9.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.2/asm-tree-9.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.2/asm-analysis-9.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.2/asm-commons-9.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/colt/colt/1.2.0/colt-1.2.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/63.1/icu4j-63.1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/tapestry/tapestry/4.0.2/tapestry-4.0.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.19/htmlunit-2.19.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xalan-2.7.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.2/serializer-2.7.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.1/httpmime-4.5.1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.17/htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22/nekohtml-1.9.22.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/cssparser/cssparser/0.9.18/cssparser-0.9.18.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.2.13.v20150730/websocket-client-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.4.44.v20210927/websocket-common-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.4.44.v20210927/websocket-api-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-webapp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-xml-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-security-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util-ajax/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-servlets-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-continuation-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-annotations-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-plus-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-jndi-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jsp/9.4.44.v20210927/apache-jsp-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1.2/jetty-schemas-3.1.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.5.70/apache-jsp-8.5.70.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.5.70/apache-el-8.5.70.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/ecj/3.19.0/ecj-3.19.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/gwtplatform/gwtp-mvp-client/1.6/gwtp-mvp-client-1.6.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/gwtplatform/gwtp-clients-common/1.6/gwtp-clients-common-1.6.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/gwtplatform/gwtp-mvp-shared/1.6/gwtp-mvp-shared-1.6.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material/2.8.2/gwt-material-2.8.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-jquery/2.8.2/gwt-material-jquery-2.8.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/elemental2/elemental2-core/1.0.0-RC1/elemental2-core-1.0.0-RC1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/jsinterop/base/1.0.0-RC1/base-1.0.0-RC1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/elemental2/elemental2-promise/1.0.0-RC1/elemental2-promise-1.0.0-RC1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/elemental2/elemental2-dom/1.0.0-RC1/elemental2-dom-1.0.0-RC1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/elemental2/elemental2-media/1.0.0-RC1/elemental2-media-1.0.0-RC1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-themes/2.8.2/gwt-material-themes-2.8.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-addins/2.8.2/gwt-material-addins-2.8.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-table/2.8.2/gwt-material-table-2.8.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/inject/gin/2.1.2/gin-2.1.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/nmorel/gwtjackson/gwt-jackson/0.15.4/gwt-jackson-0.15.4.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.6/jackson-annotations-2.9.6.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.6/jackson-annotations-2.9.6-sources.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/squareup/javapoet/1.0.0/javapoet-1.0.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/ekotrope/gwt-completablefuture/1.0.0/gwt-completablefuture-1.0.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.2/junit-4.13.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.30/lombok-1.18.30.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.5/slf4j-api-2.0.5.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.5/slf4j-simple-2.0.5.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/vertispan/shortcut/gwt-shortcut-trapper/1.0.0-alpha-1/gwt-shortcut-trapper-1.0.0-alpha-1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/ektorp/org.ektorp/1.5.0/org.ektorp-1.5.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3/httpclient-4.3.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/httpcore-4.3.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.3/httpclient-cache-4.3.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.4/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.7/jackson-core-2.6.7.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.7/jackson-databind-2.6.7.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/findbugs/annotations/1.3.2/annotations-1.3.2.jar:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity/target/Entity/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-entity-dao/target/EntityDAO/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.4.0-b180830.0359/jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/gwt-material-am4charts/2.8.2/gwt-material-am4charts-2.8.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/restygwt/restygwt/2.2.7/restygwt-2.2.7.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/jackson-databind-2.9.6-sources.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-util/target/Util/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-common/target/Commons/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.13.3/itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar:/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-fiscal/target/Fiscal/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/realityforge/gwt/qr_code/gwt-qr-code/0.03/gwt-qr-code-0.03.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/realityforge/braincheck/braincheck/1.9.0/braincheck-1.9.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/realityforge/javax/annotation/javax.annotation/1.0.0/javax.annotation-1.0.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.3.1/maven-resources-plugin-3.3.1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.26/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.5.1/plexus-utils-3.5.1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/3.3.1/maven-filtering-3.3.1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.55.0/htmlunit-2.55.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-text/1.9/commons-text-1.9.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.13/httpmime-4.5.13.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.55.0/htmlunit-core-js-2.55.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/neko-htmlunit/2.55.0/neko-htmlunit-2.55.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.1/xercesImpl-2.12.1.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-cssparser/1.10.0/htmlunit-cssparser-1.10.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.8.0/commons-net-3.8.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/brotli/dec/0.1.2/dec-0.1.2.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/com/shapesecurity/salvation2/3.0.0/salvation2-3.0.0.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.4.44.v20210927/websocket-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-client/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Users/work2/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode -superDevMode -war /Users/work2/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/gwt/srr-shop-manager.cb9c165f/srr-shop-manager.5cafa7fa/run/www -sourceLevel 1.11 -remoteUI 7903:IntelliJIdea -startupUrl index.html com.srr.ShopManager
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52523', transport: 'socket'
Running CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.11, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, /Users/work2/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/gwt/srr-shop-manager.cb9c165f/srr-shop-manager.5cafa7fa/run/www, -logLevel, INFO, -style, OBFUSCATED, com.srr.ShopManager]
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: /var/folders/vy/s37nw9k51md77vhjhxglhshc0000gp/T/gwt-codeserver-1183486925327792487.tmp
   [WARN] Deactivated PrecompressLinker
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @1001ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
   Loading Java files in com.srr.ShopManager.
   Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI$Mutable
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:162)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener.runCodeServer(SuperDevListener.java:112)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener.start(SuperDevListener.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.ensureCodeServerListener(DevMode.java:666)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.doStartup(DevModeBase.java:785)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:551)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:888)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:705)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI$Mutable
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 14 more
   Module setup completed in 12547 ms
[ERROR] Error saving compilation unit to cache file: /Users/work2/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/gwt/srr-shop-manager.cb9c165f/srr-shop-manager.5cafa7fa/run/gwt-unitCache/gwt-unitCache-7b9fbb59f8661539c34f46974ce5fb573aac79fc-18CAE75E829AF224BF18DEE97AC379EF-0000018BCC9F0CF9
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:161)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.writeObject(DiskCacheToken.java:73)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1072)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1529)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1451)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1194)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1585)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:451)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.writeObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:230)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1072)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1529)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1451)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1194)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:358)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCacheDir$OpenFile.writeUnit(PersistentUnitCacheDir.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCacheDir.writeUnit(PersistentUnitCacheDir.java:194)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$BackgroundService$6.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:444)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52523', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was wondering if you have any experience or insights into using Jetty 11 with GWT. ? (and sorry about my confusion)

and GWT versions like
[image: Dependencies]

Thx to all for the brilliant GWT :) and some fun
[image]

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: for the color coding only sorry, Intellij dosen't copy the colors :(

Comment: Colors are not really needed to understand these logs. It is clear which line is a warning or error.

Comment: Did you mention the version of GWT?

Comment: all latest from maven pom  and  --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC error can be safely ignored, this is logged only when that method of fixing a memory leak no longer exists.

However, you cannot change the DevMode classpath to use Jetty 11 instead of Jetty 9. Instead, if you want to use Jetty 11 to run your own application, run it separately from GWT `DevMode` and pass `-noserver` to DevMode, and use the `-war` argument to specify where to write compiled JS so that your own application server can serve it. Alternatively, use `CodeServer` instead of `DevMode` (and use `-launcherDir` instead of `-war` to specify where to send compiled JS.

Comment: June 1st, 2022 marks the end of community support for the Jetty 9.4.x release branch
https://eclipse.dev/jetty/download.php#version-table
Maybe you can point me howto upgrade it for everyone !? :)

Comment: GWT 2.11 was just released, and still runs on Java 8. Jetty 10 and above, on the other hand, do not run on Java 8. We've been suggesting the steps above for years to manage your own server, and as of GWT 2.11, we are formally deprecating running your app inside DevMode, see https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9863 and the linked PR. GWT 2.12 will not run on Java 8, but making the decision for everyone about whether to use jakarta-servlet or javax-servlet isn't a choice we want to make.

Comment: wow, great news & good work :)

Comment: Why  isn't it on https://mvnrepository.com ? or howto get it ?
Upon release, your component will be published to Central: this typically occurs within 30 minutes, though updates to search can take up to four hours.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're searching, but it is on maven central https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.gwtproject/gwt-servlet and mvnrepository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gwtproject/gwt-servlet. For future back-and-forth, consider using the mailing list or come chat with us at https://matrix.to/#/#gwtproject_gwt:gitter.im